# What's the difference between WebClient DefaultCredentials and NetworkCredentials?

Tags: c#, webclient, credentials

For some reason my WebClient app that used to work using `DefaultCredentials` now gives me a 401 Unauthorized. Using `NetworkCredentials` with the exact same ID and PW works.

Something must have changed on the web server, but I have no control of that. I just find it strange that there is a difference between `DefaultCredentials` and `NetworkCredentials`.

What could possibly be the difference and how to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx) and this?

They say DefaultCredentials represents the credentials of the local user. But I cannot answer you why it was working in the past. Username and password is the same like in the past?

Or do you mean another property as WebClient.Credentials ?

Comment: Yes, I am logged into my Windows machine with the same ID/PW as I pass to NetworkCredentials.

Comment: Is your computer member of a domain? If so, is the Webserver in the same domain?

Comment: Yes my domain and the web server are the same. Forgot to mention that the request is via https if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is the folder on your webserver protected with `Basic Authentification`? You cannot pass default credentials with basic authentification. I found this by using google: [look last post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t108807-downloadfile-and-credentials.html).

Comment: It works now! My web admin says it was not set to Basic Auth and all he did was view the admin screen, then it started working. I'll therefor accept this answer....